# What is the difference between 'describe' and 'test' in Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have just start learning unit testing in **Vue.js** using **Jest**, and I want to know when to use **describe** and when to use **test** ?

**TodoApp.vue** Component :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>TodoApp Componenent</h1>
    <div v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id" data-test="todo">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoApp",
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Learn Vue.js 3',
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**TodoApp.spec.js**

**1#** Unit test using `test`

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import TodoApp from '@/components/TodoApp'

test('renders a todo', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(TodoApp)

  const todo = wrapper.get('[data-test="todo"]')

  expect(todo.text()).toBe('Learn Vue.js 2')
})
```

**2#** Unit test using `describe`

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import TodoApp from '@/components/TodoApp'

describe('TodoApp', () => {
  it('renders a todo', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(TodoApp)

    const todo = wrapper.get('[data-test="todo"]')
  
    expect(todo.text()).toBe('Learn Vue.js 2')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`describe` is a way to create a suite of tests. `test` and `it` are a single test case in a suite (or not). The names are chained together. It is helpful sometimes to think of the names of tests as sentences.

```
describe('when a user does x', () => {
   beforeEach(() => x());

   it('should do something', () => expect(something).toBe(true));

   it('should not do something else', () => expect(somethingElse).toBe(false));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`test` and `it` are just aliases of one another-- they both do the same thing.  `describe` is used to define a "suite" of tests, and will contain one or more nested `it` or `test` function.